# Problema ao conectar porta 80 Apache

Tags: apache, postgresql, webserver

Estou tentando usar `BitNami Stack MAPP 5.5.30-0` ( Para o Apache Web Server, PostgreSQL)

Quando eu tento configurar o Apache Web Server eu recebo este erro : "*Cannot bind to port 80. It is probably taken by another application or you don't have enough privileges.*" Ele provavelmente é tomado por outro aplicativo ou você não tem privilégios suficientes .

- **Eu não quero mudar e usar outra porta . Eu realmente quero usar a porta 80.**
- Eu não sei o aplicativo está usando a porta 80 .
- Estou usando um MAC OS X Yosemite.

Eu tentei este comando:

```
sudo lsof -i ' : 80'
```

Mas nada está sendo executado nessa porta .

Abri o `httpd.conf` e eu tentei mudar a porta de escuta para 80. Mas ainda não está funcionando .

Alguém pode me ajudar ? obrigado

Comment: o comando não parece correto... tente isso `lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN` ou `sudo lsof -i ':80'` (sem espaços)

Comment: Tentei esse comando mas deu essa mensagem:   ` lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i 4TCP:
lsof 4.87
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvV] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
[+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information. `

Comment: tentei tambem o comando: `sudo lsof -i ':80'` mas nao aparece nada, só se tiver com algum site aberto no navegador.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe correta para verificar se um serviço está escutando determinada porta é:

sudo lsof -i :80

Answer (score 0):

O aplicativo que está usando a porta 80 é provavelmente um Apache proveniente de um AMP (Apache MySQL PHP) que já vem pré-instalado ou pré-configurado no Mac, desde a versão OSX 10.10 Yosemite.

Ao usar corretamente o comando no terminal de seu Mac (como o colega listou acima):

```
    sudo lsof -i :80
```

Provavelmente serão listados alguns processos httpd que estão utilizando a porta 80.
Para finalizá-los basta digitar o comando:

```
    sudo apachectl stop
```

Depois tente listar novamente os processos que estão utilizando a porta 80 e você será que nada será listado, novamente usando o comando:

```
    sudo lsof -i :80
```

Caso não funcione, você pode tentar ainda iniciar o Apache do Mac com o comando:

```
    sudo apachectl start
```

e depois finalizá-lo com o comando:

```
    sudo apachectl stop
```

PRONTO! RESOLVIDO!
Agora pode utilizar o serviço Apache Web Server de sua preferência.
Espero ter conseguido ajudar.

Conseguir resolver esse problema após ler esse tutorial.

Segue para mais informações:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/